# Disable certain selected option for its counterpart from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdowns. When I select option **One**, I want option **Five** to be disabled from the second dropdown.

How can I achieve that. Below is the dropdown code.

```
<form>
  <select class="mySelect">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>

<form>
  <select class="mySelect">
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4s2qoo6/) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all one thing you should notice that you **cannot** use same ids for multiple elements in one single page. Id has to be unique for each element.

In your case you can change it to `class`:

```js
$('.mySelect:eq(0)').change(function(){
  $('option:contains(Five)').prop('disabled', this.value == "One");
}).change(); // <---this makes sure to fire the change event on doc ready
             // because you have option with value "one" already selected.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="mySelect">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>

<form>
  <select class="mySelect">
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: hehehe... why downvote me? just you're angry?? XDDDD it's nice how people like you is only searching for rep....

Comment: calm down guys, Thanks for answers.

Comment: You are welcome @Suraj. don't worrry no problems here at all.

Answer (score 0):

First change id's (cannot be the same), after add `disable` and id to option five (one is default) and check wich is selected in first dropdown

```
<option disabled>Five</option>

$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    //if($("#mySelect").selected() == "one")
    if ($("#mySelect").val() == "One")
       $("#five").prop("disabled", true);
    else 
       $("#five").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4s2qoo6/2/)